# Developer community was not created

Tags: apigee

I tried to create a developer community using  URL : http://apigee.com/docs/content/developer-services-portal-request but Apigee does not respond with a developer portal URL. Please let me know how to create a developer portal from Apigee tool. I already created an organization.
The organization's name is damuorgn. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the developer portal product is no longer available to users with Developer (free) accounts.  Users with paid accounts can have one provisioned for them by requesting it on the Support Portal.

The documentation will be updated to reflect this change.